# What does this part of my SQL query mean?

Tags: sql, postgresql

`sum( (record_id is NULL AND joined.table_id is NULL)::int )`
I know the sum returns the sum of the column entries, but what will this expression (... and...) return, can it be compared with this expression (.. + ..), and what does this ()::int?? convert result to int?

i dont know will return this expression, on my sampling will returned number of integer

Comment: That looks like a very ugly and quirky way of counting rows where both `record_id` and `table_id` are null. MySQL has no real BOOL type and even if it did, `SUM(bool)` would make no sense. `::int` converts `true` into `1`

Comment: `BIT` is often used to represent boolean values but once again, `SUM(bit)` makes no sense `::int` will convert the BIT value into an `int` that can be summed

Answer (score 4):

It is a more complicated way to write

```
count(*) FILTER (WHERE record_id IS NULL
                   AND joined.table_id IS NULL)
```

Answer (score 1):

`(record_id is NULL AND joined.table_id is NULL)::int` will return 1 iff both `record_id` and `joined.table_id` are null.

Therefore, `sum( (record_id is NULL AND joined.table_id is NULL)::int )` will return the number of rows in which both `record_id` and `joined.table_id` are null.